# One large relations table or multiple small relations

Tags: database, relationship

Say I have tables: User, Role, Content, and Zone.

Let's say content X needs to be accessible to non-admin users in Zone1.

Should I create one large related table that has FKs to these tables in one row, or should I break it up into smaller linked tables like UserToRole, UserToZone, and ContentToZone and use joins?

Comment: Each logical entity should be in it's own table.  Cardinality between each of the elements in the table help determine if the relationship is 1:M or M:M.  All M:M need to have an an associative/junction table.  The 1:M relationhips don't.  To answer the question of one table or smaller tables.  Smaller.  A user belongs to one or more roles.  you don't want to repeat that association just because they have access to multiple zones or content

Comment: @xQbert Thank you! So basically if they want one end-all-be-all table it'd be better to just make a view based on all these linked tables?

Comment: If someone needs to see the user, role content zone ID's and relationships yes I would have a query/view/report for that; I wouldn't however have a single table containing all 4 elements for the mere fact that it fails 3rd normal form.  We are duplicating data which makes maintenance more challenging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

went with multiple smaller transaction tables per @xQbert's response.